# running external .exe on button click c++. How to?

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++

I am creating a simple GUI in C++ which have few buttons in it. I want to launch some external .exe files when i click on these buttons.

What's the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In its simplest form: [`system("c:\\path\\to\\binary.exe");`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/).
If you need more control, use something like [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the *system()* solution, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703890/how-can-i-create-a-process-in-a-portable-manner/1799962#1799962) for an explaination. You should use CreateProcess for executables and ShellExecute to open files with their associated application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CreateProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can also use system() but system() doesn't return until the process you called exits.